# Access raw JSON data in the init(from decoder: Decoder) method

Tags: swift, json-deserialization, decoding, codable

Say I have this structure of data returned from backend:

```
struct DummyItem: Decodable {
    let number: Int
    let name: String
}

struct DummyResponse {
    let items: [DummyItem]
    let meta: String
}
```

I also have this helper struct to skip objects decoding of which has failed:

```
struct OptionalObject<Base: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let value: Base?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self.value = try container.decode(Base.self)
        } catch {
            self.value = nil
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it like so:

```
extension DummyResponse: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case items, meta
    }
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        let nullableItems = try container.decode([OptionalObject<DummyItem>].self, forKey: .items)
        self.items = nullableItems.compactMap({ $0.value })
        self.meta = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .meta)
    }
}
```

So for example, when I receive some corrupted `DummyItem` in the backend response, I'm still gonna get the `DummyResponse`, but that item is going to be skipped

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "name": "first"
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            "name": "second"
        },
        {
            "number": 3,
            "name": null
        },
    ],
    "meta": "Metadata"
}
```

When this happens, how can I access the raw JSON data of the problematic object?
I assume this can be done in the `catch` block of the `OptionalObject` struct. It seems like an easy task (the decoder must somehow have access to this raw data that it's trying to decode, right?)

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to let `name` be optional in `DummyItem` instead and then filter the result afterwards into correct values and incorrect values? You could also map the correct values into another type where `name` isn’t optional if that is important.

Comment: The `JSONDecoder` unfortunately doesn't give access to the piece of `Data` it's treating... It would be a nice feature for some edge cases...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yeah I guess I'll end up doing that. I was looking for a universal approach to catch badly formatted pieces of data from BE (e.g. user posts, user profiles, items from 3d party APIs etc). Your second suggestion will do the job (mapping to another struct where `name` isn't optional) but it will require going to multiple different places and adding a lot of extra logic.
Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Decoder` contains a `userInfo` dictionary that you can put anything you like and it will be accessible during decoding. Also during decoding you have access to the current array of coding keys (`decoder.codingPath`) (e.g. `["items", "number"]` if the "number" if being decoded).

So you can store in the `userInfo` the JSON data and along with the coding path you can get the JSON data that are corrupt.

The following example should work as you intended.

```
struct OptionalObject<Base: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let value: Base?

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        do {
            self.value = try container.decode(Base.self)
        } catch {
            print("Found corrupt data at \(decoder.codingPath)")
            print("Corrupt data \(decoder.currentlyDecodingJSON())")
            self.value = nil
        }
    }
}

extension Decoder {
    func currentlyDecodingJSON() -> Any? {
        guard let json = userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "jsonDictionary")!] else {
            return nil
        }

        return jsonAtPath(codingPath, in: json)
    }

    func jsonAtPath<T: Sequence>(_ path: T, in otherJSON: Any?) -> Any? where T.Element == CodingKey {
        guard let key = path.first(where: {_ in true}) else { return otherJSON }

        if let index = key.intValue {
            guard let array = otherJSON as? [Any] else { return otherJSON }
            return jsonAtPath(codingPath.dropFirst(), in: array[index])
        }
        guard let dictionary = otherJSON as? [String: Any] else { return otherJSON }
        return jsonAtPath(codingPath.dropFirst(), in: dictionary[key.stringValue])

    }
}

/// jsonString contains the string you have provided in the question description
let jsonData = Data(jsonString.utf8)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
decoder.userInfo[CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "jsonDictionary")!] = jsonDictionary

let decodedData = try decoder.decode(DummyResponse.self, from: jsonData)
```

The above will print

```
Found corrupt data at [CodingKeys(stringValue: "items", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 2", intValue: 2)]
Corrupt data Optional({
    name = "<null>";
    number = 3;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a pretty simple solution, will try it!

Comment: @DanyloKurylo If you try it and it works please accept the answer in order to also help others that face similar problems. Thanks.

Comment: Ended up going with a slightly modified version of this as it's easy, and as far as I understand passing the JSON data to userInfo isn't expensive

Answer (score 3):

As described, this is impossible. JSONDecoder doesn't operate on Data internally. It operates on either an [NSDictionary (produced by JSONSerialization)](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/2d23cf3dc07951ed2b988608d08d7a54cc53b26e/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L1200-L1214) or a [`JSONValue` enum](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/2d23cf3dc07951ed2b988608d08d7a54cc53b26e/Sources/Foundation/JSONSerialization.swift#L629-L637), depending on the platform. (In the new swift-foundation, it's [a little more complicated](https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation/blob/629b1463fab3bfa6c1d7243030975762b170b445/Sources/FoundationEssentials/JSON/JSONScanner.swift#L68), but the point is the same.) By the time it gets calling `init(from:)`, the underlying Data is no longer available.

To do what you want, you will need to parse the JSON by hand. This isn't as hard as it sounds, and I do it a bit, including to achieve things similar to what you're describing. But it does tend to require copying a lot of code out of stdlib in order to make internal types public.

Given that you seem to only care about "unexpected JSON" rather than actually corrupted JSON (i.e. not valid JSON), then the technique I generally prefer is to parse things into a struct like [JSONValue](https://github.com/rnapier/RNAJSON/tree/main/Sources/JSONValue) (this is a custom one I built with a bunch of helper function to make it nicer to use), and then replace `Decodable` with an `init(json: JSONValue) throws`. These initializers tend to be quite easy to write, and very easy to extend with error handling and the like. I haven't particularly bundled it up into a reusable package. I tend to just copy this stuff into my projects and adapt it to the local problem.

If you pull over the stdlib JSONValue implementation of JSONDecoder (linked above), then you can also make the [JSONDecoderImpl](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/2d23cf3dc07951ed2b988608d08d7a54cc53b26e/Sources/Foundation/JSONDecoder.swift#L211-L224) public, and then you can automatically decode Decodables from JSONValues when you want to.

There's no trivial answer to all of this, but if it's important to your project, it's definitely all very doable. The JSONValue code is tedious, but not really that complicated (vs the NSDictionary code, which is a real pain to work with).

I touch on some of this, and discuss similar topics in my [Advanced Codable talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-k_vipGhugQ), which may be useful.

Comment: That’s very interesting, thanks for a detailed answer. I’ll definitely check out the talk!